# Simple video editing application - should I use WPF or MFC?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, mfc, video-processing

I am about to start making a simple little video editing application, and I was trying to decide what system to create the GUI in.  I know a lot about the Windows API, and actually, all of my programs thus far have been written in it.  I would really like to use the new WPF framework though; however, I am a bit concerned about the fact that C# may not be ideal for a performance-oriented application.  And I'm not positive, but I don't think it is possible to use SIMD instructions in C#??  Of course, my video editing program will use DirectX, and then I've read about problems of using that in C#.  So then I had the idea that maybe I'd write the "core" of the program in C++ and somehow link it to its GUI through DLLs or something.  Of course, that could be really messy... Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you going to use DirectShow for video editing?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use MFC.

WPF has a future, and skills learned in it are saleable. Not so sure about MFC...

I wouldn't worry about performance of C# versus C++; there have been several benchmarks that show an approx. 10% speed increase using C++. The major issue is object creation/deletion. Reducing this is one of the main issues with C# performance.

Answer (score 1):

Why not managed C++ and either winforms or c#/WPF ui?